# Homemade chocolate problem!

Tags: chocolate

Good afternoon all!
Just a query regarding making your own chocolate, I literally did the exact same process yesterday and it turned out great, however the batch today has ended up a disaster.

Let me explain my process:

1 cup cacao butter melted in a double boiler (I was very careful to make sure no water gets in)
I then added 1/2 cup of honey, vanilla extract, pinch of salt, 1tsp soy lecithin powder, and 1 cup of cacao powder, and mixed in the double boiler.

The consistency is now very fatty, as opposed to silky and smooth which is what I got yesterday. 
The mixture isn’t consistent, it’s clumpy and then really thin liquid inside there too, which prevents it from all blending together smoothly.

I was pretty confident I got no water in, the only thing I can think of is maybe I cooked it at too high of a temp? Did I need to wait for the butter to cool before mixing the ingredients first?

Any suggestions appreciated!![image]

Answer (score 7):

The chocolate has "seized". This is what happens when you add water into the melted chocolate.

> I was pretty confident I got no water in.

No, you added honey and vanilla extract. Both contain water.

The standard solution to seized chocolate is to stir in boiling water, a bit at a time, until the mixture is smooth. The result is not useful for confectionery, but can be used to make hot chocolate or chocolate sauce.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! The first batch I made had honey and vanilla extract in also, so how could this have happened ?

Comment: @JacobRogganSmith You're rolling the dice, basically. Chocolate can absorb some amount of water without seizing, particularly if the water is added very gradually, for similar reasons to why you need to gradually add oil to mayonnaise. The likelihood of seizing would also depend on how quickly the lecithin was distributed, and even on whether you added the lecithin and the honey to the same part of the bowl.

Comment: If you want to maximize your chances of success without changing the recipe, you should melt the cocoa butter and thoroughly mix in everything other than the vanilla and the honey. Then, mix the vanilla and the honey with each other, and _slowly_ drizzle the result into the chocolate while stirring the chocolate furiously (easiest with two people).

Comment: My seized chocolate becomes fudge.